# PowerShell reading property file

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need read properties from config file. 
I can do it with

```
ConvertFrom-StringData(Get-Content test.conf | out-String)
```

But in this file I have param

```
username=intranet\sysTestAcc
```

And when it's try to parse it I had error: 
Unrecognized escape sequence \s.

How can I fix that with script? I can't change file before running script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace the `\` with `\\`:

```
# The first '\\' is a regex with a '\' escape to create a literal '\'
# The second '\\' is a literal replacement (non-regex) that inserts two '\'
ConvertFrom-StringData ((Get-Content test.conf -Raw) -replace '\\','\\')
```

Answer (score 2):

You must escape the \ with another one. i.e.

```
username=intranet\\sysTestAcc
```

At that point ConvertFrom-StringData will be happy.

You might also use the "-Raw" parameter for Get-Content instead of pipeline into Out-String.

Comment: I can't because I have first version of Powershell.
And the problem is that I can't replace before running script.